# How to convert from world coordinates to camera coordinates

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, 3d

In the world coordinate system, there are objects with rotation values `rx1,ry1,rz1` and position values `px1,py1,pz1`.

Similarly, there is an camera in the world coordinate system with rotation values `rx2,ry2,rz2` and position values `px2,py2,pz2`.

What formula can be used to convert `rx1,ry1,rz1,px1,py1,pz1` to the camera coordinate system?

The up vector of the camera is the Y-axis, always oriented toward the object near the world origin.

The camera and the model are supposed to move within the range as shown in the following gif image.
[image]

I would like to use Python to do the calculations, but I am open to any other answers, including other Unity C# or mathematical statements.

You are welcome to have commentary in quaternions or in matrices instead of euler angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Unity c# for the position you can simply use the built-in

```
var localPosition = camera.transform.InverseTransformPoint(theObject.transform.position);
```

for the rotation you can use

```
var localRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(camera.transform.rotation) * theObject.transform.rotation;
```

This should give you the `localPosition` and `localRotation` in the coordinate space of the `camera`.